# adding char grid to jPanel

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, gridworld

I have two classes, one where the grid is set and the other where a GUI is made. I want the grid from the first class to be inserted into jPanel in the second class. The first grid is a char grid and is filled with numbers that are randomly initiated. I am having trouble working out how to insert the grid into the jpanel as this is more complicated than expected. I have tried many things but havent had any luck..Any help?

```
//set grid class

    public void setgrid() {
            Random ran = new Random();      
            for (int i = 0; i < X; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < Y; j++) {
                    int num = ran.nextInt(10); 
                    if (num == 4) { 
                        grid[i][j] = 'F'; 
                    } else if (num == 9) { 
                        grid[i][j] = 'O'; 
                    } else {
                        grid[i][j] = ' '; 
                    }}}


// Panel Class
    Panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(X, Y));
            for (int i = 0; i < X; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < Y; j++) {
                    world[i][j] = new JPanel();
                    world[i][j].setBackground(Color.white);
                    world[i][j].setBorder(BorderFactory
                            .createLineBorder(Color.black));
                    Panel.add(world[i][j]);
```

NOT SURE WHAT TO ADD HERE TO ADD THE GRID INTO THE PANEL

Comment: What's not working about it?

Comment: im unsure how to add the grid to the panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"I am having trouble working out how to insert the grid into the jpanel as this is more complicated than expected. I have tried many things but havent had any luck..Any help?"*

Not sure what exactly you're trying to or what you're doing wrong, but one thing I can suggest is to use `JLabel`s. They take text as parameters, which show the text in the label. `JPanel`s on the other hand, need to be drawn on (meaning you need to actually draw the text yourself).

Test out this program, to see what I'm talking about

[image]

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DrawGrid {

    public DrawGrid() {
        int[][] grid = getGrid();

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(10, 10));
        for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
                panel.add(new JLabel(String.valueOf(grid[i][j])));
            }
        }

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);


    }

    public int[][] getGrid() {
        int[][] grid = new int[10][10];
        for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
                grid[i][j] = i;
            }
        }
        return grid;

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DrawGrid();

    }

}
```

---

Here's the code where I add the `JLabel`s to the `JPanel`

```
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(10, 10));
    for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
            panel.add(new JLabel(String.valueOf(grid[i][j])));
        }
    }
```

The same way you add borders and background to the `JPanel`, you can also do with `JLabel`